# Function, called during the object destruction

Tags: c++, destructor

Could you provide code example reflecting the following rule:

N3797 c++14, section 3.6.3/2:

> If a function contains a block-scope object of static or thread
>   storage duration that has been destroyed and the function is called
>   during the destruction of an object with static or thread storage
>   duration, the program has undefined behavior if the flow of control
>   passes through the definition of the previously destroyed block-scope
>   object.

Comment: There are many ways to write code where this paragraph applies. It seems that you want it for illustration because there is something about the paragraph you do not understand. Can you tell us more about what exactly you don't understand so that it can be illustrated?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Could you explain what does _flow of control passes through the definition of some objec_. It is a bit unclear for me.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Informally speaking, if you were stepping through the code in a debugger, it means the definition would become the next step.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: lines executed in this order: 40, 41, 42, while line 41 contains a definition of a function local static.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you are:

```
void theFunction()
{
  static std::unique_ptr<int> foo { new int(42) };
}

struct Creator
{
  Creator() { theFunction(); }
};


struct Destroyer
{
  ~Destroyer() { theFunction(); }
};

Destroyer d;
Creator c;

int main()
{}
```

`d` is created first, but its constructor does nothing. Then, `c` is created, and as part of its initialisation, `theFunction()` is called, which causes the block-scope static-storage-duration variable `foo` to be initialised.

Then, at program exit, static-storage objects are destroyed in reverse order of construction. So `foo` is destroyed, and then `c`. Finally, `d` is destroyed, but its destructor calls `theFunction()`, which causes control flow to reach the definition of `foo` again, after it's been destroyed already.

The standard quote you've shown ascribes undefined behaviour to this.

Comment: Good answer. Would it be even better if foo had a non-trivial destructor?

Comment: @david.pfx Edited in :-)

Comment: Thanks! Like the OP I read the para without really 'seeing' the horrible scenario it's talking about. The sample code makes it obvious.

Comment: As foo gets destroyed before c, wouldn't it be simpler to demonstrate U.B. by removing one struct and call theFunction() from both the constructor and the destructor?

Comment: I think that foo *must* be an object to apply the rule. Now it's ok.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini With `int bar = 42;`, `bar` is also an object, of type `int`. In C++, "object" is not restricted to class-type in any way.

Comment: @MaartenHilferink With two global objects, you don't have to know the details of whether `foo` or `c` get created/destroyed first.

Comment: @Angew Nice explanation! Thanks! One more question. Could we replace block-scope `static unique_ptr<int> foo { new int(42); }` to any other block-scope variable with static storage duration?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I don't quite follow; as per the quote, the rule applies to *any* block-scope variable with static or thread storage duration.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I originally had an `int` there, it applies just as well. `std::unique_ptr` was the first class with a non-trivial destructor which came to mind; with such a class, it may be more obvious *why* the behaviour is prescribed as undefined.

Comment: Isn't the construction order `d`, `foo`, `c`? Construction doesn't complete until the constructor returns?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Counter {
  int *ptr;
  Counter() {ptr = new int; *ptr = 0;};
  int next() {return (*ptr)++;}
  ~Counter() {delete ptr;}
};

int function() {
  static Counter c;
  return c.next();
}

struct Obj {
  ~Obj() {cout<<function()<<endl;}  
};

Obj obj;

int main() {
  cout<<function()<<endl;
}
```

First, obj is being created. Then main calls function and Counter c is being created. When the program terminates it is possible that Counter c is destroyed before obj. When obj is destroyed the function should be executed but its static variable is gone... so undefined behavior.